# Convert string to byte as it is

Tags: c#, byte

I have seen many questions regarding this conversion,but neither worked for me.

I have a string with value as

string i=10;

I need to convert the string to byte as 0x10

I tried

```
 Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(i);
```

It doesn't worked. 
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert from `string` to `byte` using the `Convert` class. It allows you to specify a base as second parameter.

So if  you want to convert a hexadecimal string to byte, you can use this:

```
string i = "10";
Convert.ToByte(i, 16) // => 16
```